# Magento 2.3.4 - How I can add attributes to Categories

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, category, magento2.3.4

I want to add two attributes in the admin for categories, one textarea, and one text input, I already add the attributes in the database, and I use this code

```
Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="content">

    <field name="cat_short_description">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code</item>
                        <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                    <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">cat_short_description</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
                <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Textarea</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
                <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string"></item>

            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
                <field name="title_review">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Second Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>


</fieldset>
</form>
```

the code is okay but I don't have that **Use Default Value** checkbox when changing the **Store View**, what is wrong or how I can add  **Use Default Value** checkbox?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to add the "**SCOPE_STORE**" while creating the custom category attribute.

You must need to add the

```
\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
```

For the **global** variable

Check the below code.

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
    'cat_short_description',
    [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Category Short Description',
        'input' => 'textarea',
        'sort_order' => 100,
        'source' => '',
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => null,
        'group' => 'General Information',
        'backend' => ''
    ]
);
```

Or you can change directly in the **database** by the below way **(Not Tested)**.

Find your attribute code in "**eav_attribute**" and search it's **attribute_id** in "**catalog_eav_attribute**" and change the **is_globle** to **0 (Zero)**,
Then reindex and check.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi thank you, and if this attribute is already created, is there anyway to modify? I can add this through the phpmyadmin?

Comment: You can do it by UpgradeData script, Check this: https://webkul.com/blog/update-product-custom-attribute-scope-in-magento-2/

Comment: Here you can use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, instead of \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,

Comment: I got it but is not anyway to change this directly in database?

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check.

Comment: Hi I try both variants is not work

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider`.

Example :

```
<?php

namespace Your\Namespace;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider as CategoryDataProvider;

class DataProvider extends CategoryDataProvider
{

    /**
     * Display "Use Default Value" checkbox
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getFieldsMap()
    {
        $parentFieldMap = parent::getFieldsMap();
        array_push($parentFieldMap['display_settings'], 'your_attribute');

        return $parentFieldMap;
    }
}
```